# Saving into a temp csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to save into a temp csv file. Although the snippet does not return an error/traceback, it returns an empty temp csv file with the name of the first column from the PermitData csv (even though the next syntax is supposed to skip over that). What is wrong with the snippet? Please provide your meticulous feedback.

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\Python Files\\output.csv', 'w') as output:
    with open('C:\\Users\\Python Files\\PermitData.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        output.write(next(reader)[0].replace('\t', ' ') + '\n')
        data = list(reader)
        for item in data:
            item = item[0].split(' ')
            if len(item) > 6:
                item[1] = item[1].title()
                output.write(' '.join(item) + '\n')

print 'Output created'
```

The row[1] in the PermitData.csv has addresses outlined as:

```
1234 PRESTON ROAD
4587 RAINING COURT
```

I need them like below so I am using the title() to convert the addresses to:

```
1234 Preston Road
4587 Raining Court
```

Since it is inadvisable and not viable to write directly into the PermitData.csv file I am creating a temp file. If there is a way to write directly into the original source, in this case PermitData.csv, please let me know how it is sensibly possible.

Comment: That "data" variable is a 2-dimensional list. When iterating through each item in data, the items are also lists. You can't split a list, only a string. When you say `len(item)` that'll give you the number of elements in the "item" list. Not the number of characters in a string.

Comment: Reassigning to `item` is not a good idea. It makes the code hard to understand and debug. Try to find descriptive names for each variable instead. It really helps with figuring out bugs.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you add some input and output example.

Comment: Thanks Anyany, please find my post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do what you need it to.

- I've separated the opening & closings of the files.
- It seems you're using spaces as a delimiter, so that has to be
  specified.
- I've also copied the data from the original 2D list to another for
  modification. Copying isn't necessary, you could just create an empty
  2D list and append to it.
- We're setting the `.title()` function to each element of the list.
  You can use conditionals if you know some elements don't need it,
  like the first column.

  ```
  import csv

  with open('C:\\Users\\Python Files\\PermitData.csv', 'r') as f:
      reader = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '))

  new_data = list(reader)
  for x, line in enumerate(reader):
      for y, word in enumerate(line):
          new_data[x][y] = word.title()

  with open('C:\\Users\\Python Files\\output.csv', 'w') as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
      writer.writerows(new_data)

  print 'Output created'
  ```